# Handling european decimal format in Svelte input component: synchronization and parsing sssues

Tags: javascript, input, formatting, svelte, sveltekit

I am writing an input component in Svelte. I have encountered a problem. My application is intended for the European market. In Europe, we use a comma as decimal separator.

The problem is that if the user enters a number in the European format (e.g. 12,5) into the input, Javascript will receive this as a String and mathematical operations cannot be performed on it.

So I wrote a workaround for this problem - the user is shown what they typed into the input (12,5), and the formatted value (12.5) is binded. However, the problem is that if the parent updates the input value, it is not synchronised with the displayed value. For example, when `value` is set to `""` by the parent, the change will not be visible in the input.

```
<script>
    export let value;
    export let type = 'text';

    let displayValue = value;
    
    const handleInput = (e) => {
        if (type === 'number') {
            value = formatInputNumber(e.target.value);
            displayValue = e.target.value;
        } else {
            value = e.target.value;
            displayValue = e.target.value;
        }
    };
</script>

<input
    {type}
    value={displayValue}
    on:input={handleInput}
    pattern={type === 'number' ? '[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?' : ''}
    {...$$restProps}
/>
```

A working live example: https://svelte.dev/repl/4f10a5ed9e164d4c969d61c8fd154ede?version=4.2.9

Currently, as a workaround, I use the `formatInputNumber` function every time I do some mathematical operation on values from an input. However, this is an impractical approach - my application mainly relies on mathematical operations and there are many such inputs. It is easy to accidentally forget to use this function and such a notation looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create pairs of text and numeric input, where you show the text input to the user and hide the numeric input, so when you apply a change to a text, it will be applied to the numeric field, simulating how the browser would work, except for the comma and dot differences, which you can vary as you please when the numeric input is written back. So the text would be the representation, the value you show and the numeric field would be the field you can use for your logic and internal calculations. Thusly you separate presentation from logic:

```js
function txttonum(txt, num) {
    num.value = txt.value.replace(",", ".");
    txt.value = num.value.replace(".", ",");
}

for (let context of document.querySelectorAll(".numberfields")) {
    let txt = context.querySelector("input[type=text]");
    let num = context.querySelector("input[type=number]");
    txt.addEventListener("input", function() {
        if (txt.value.indexOf(".") !== txt.value.length - 1) {
            txttonum(txt, num);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
div.numberfields input[type=number] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="numberfields">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="number">
</div>

<div class="numberfields">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="number">
</div>

<div class="numberfields">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="number">
</div>
```